# Launch a new coroutine task when the existing one gets cancelled in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to recreate a new coroutine for the task if the existing one gets cancelled because of an exception or other reasons. Currently, the only way I can detect the cancellation is via the `invokeOnCompletion` handler and I need to trigger new job creation for the cancelled task somehow, also `invokeOnCompletion` is not a suspend function so I have to do some trick there.

It's my current workaround

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel


lateinit var backGroundTask: Job

suspend fun main(): Unit = supervisorScope {
    val restartChannel = Channel<Boolean>()
    val restartBackGroundTaskListener = startListeningForRestartEvent(restartChannel)
    backGroundTask = someBackGroundTask()
    backGroundTask.invokeOnCompletion {
        launch { restartChannel.send(true) }
    }
    val restartBackGroundTask = restartBackGroundTaskIntermittently()
    delay(1000)
    restartBackGroundTask.join()
    restartBackGroundTaskListener.join()
}

fun CoroutineScope.startListeningForRestartEvent(restartEvents: Channel<Boolean>): Job =
        launch {
            for (event in restartEvents) {
                when (event) {
                    true -> {
                        println("newJob created ..")
                        backGroundTask = someBackGroundTask()
                        backGroundTask.invokeOnCompletion {
                            launch { restartEvents.send(true) }
                        }
                    }
                    false -> {}
                }
            }
        }

fun CoroutineScope.someBackGroundTask(): Job =
    launch {
        repeat(1000) {
            delay(400)
            println(it)
        }
    }

// Just to simulate the cancellation due to some reason
fun CoroutineScope.restartBackGroundTaskIntermittently(): Job =
    launch {
        repeat(1000) {
            delay(2000)
            backGroundTask.cancelAndJoin()
        }
    }
```

I already have an event loop in my code so I just wanna use that to trigger new job creation. `startListeningForRestartEvent` will continuously listen for a restart event and create a new `someBackGroundTask` when it receives `true`.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any better way to achieve this?
2. Is it ok to do `launch { restartChannel.send(true) }` inside `invokeOnCompletion`?
3. Will the `NonCancellable` coroutine help me here?

Comment: Are you sure you want to restart in the case of cancellations? Like for example, in a download manager application I click to cancel a download and it automatically starts another download? I think there is a big difference in error handling and cancellations handling. Cancellations are intentional and should be permanent. And if speaking about errors only, why not to enclose the whole body of a coroutine in a try-catch and in the case of error simply run the same code again? It doesn't require creating new coroutines which may be confusing to whoever is waiting for the coroutine to finish.

Comment: @broot maybe you are right, In the real code I'm sending some health check requests to the server and I want that job to run even if one of the post requests failed with an exception. So maybe I need to retry sending the post request again if it's failed with an exception.

Comment: @Vencat thinking about that case, you should probably just use `Result` and try-catch